# Why isn't my if statement correctly identifying my person variable?

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js

I am currently getting an undefined result for person. I am trying to execute the select statement and get a value so I can use the if statement ?

```
function createPerson(email, firstName, lastName, notificationInd) {
  const person = this.db.run(
    `select email_address 
            from users 
            where email_address = ?`,
    [email],
  );

  if (person.length > 0) {
    console.log("Cannot duplicate email");
  } else {
    this.db.run(
      `INSERT INTO users (email_address,first_name,last_name)
               VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)`,
      [email, firstName, lastName],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please go into detail? Just a title and some code is not sufficient. What exactly is the problem? Please read [ask].

Comment: You were asked for more details while you posted the question, please add some details. What is "_correctly identifying_" actually means? Do you get an error?

Comment: `person = this.db.run` ... I'd be very surprised if this ran synchronously

Comment: What is `this.db.run`?